# ocaml checking if a list is in sorted order

Tags: ocaml

I'm not exactly how to approach this but I need to check if a list is in sorted order.

This is what I am doing:

```
let rec is_sorted_aux l res = match l with
    [] -> res
  | (h1::h2::t) ->
    if (h2 > h1) then
      is_sorted_aux t false
    else 
      is_sorted_aux t true
;;
```

but this is comparing pairs of elements as in 1&&2, 3&&4, etc. and not ALL of them with their neighbors.

How would I approach this?

Comment: The language is spelt “OCaml”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `as`:

```
  | h1 :: (h2 :: _ as t) ->
```

Also, you can return as soon as a comparison fails instead of carrying `false` until the end of the list.

And you should not ignore the warning that you're getting.

Comment: In a pattern, `p as x` means to match the pattern `p` (which probably contains several parts), and also to give the name `x` to whatever matches the entire pattern p. In this case `p` is `h2 :: _`, the tail of the list.